# How to fix AmqpTimeoutException in Spring AMQP connecting to rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I write an app based on Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ broker (on Mac OS). I have started the rabbitMQ's server and it is accessible through the Admin Console. But when my Spring app tries to connect the queue, it gets `AmqpTimeoutException`. Please help me to solve this issue, I am out of options.

The important thing: a couple of times during RabbitMQ ping my Spring app established a connection, but it seemed like a coincidence. So my main suspicion is about the timeout settings, but I can't define which of them.

I tried to increase the handshake timeouts on both sides. Also, I tried the different connection settings: I changed the user from guest to test, host from 127.0.0.1 to localhost (it gives 'Connection refused').

RabbitMQ: 3.7.16,
Spring AMQP: amqp-client-5.1.2,
Spring Rabbit: spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.

My `rabbitmq.config`:

`[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].`

Listeners `rabbitmqctl status`

```
     [{clustering,25672,"::"},
      {amqp,5672,"127.0.0.1"},
      {stomp,61613,"::"},
      {mqtt,1883,"::"},
      {http,15672,"::"}]}
```

The port situation

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00037s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5672/tcp open  amqp
```

The `application.properties`:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

The code is very simple:

Spring Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfing {
    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("hello");
    }
}
```

And the queue recipient

```
@Component
public class Receiver {
    @RabbitListener(queues = "hello")
    public void receive(String in) {
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }
}
```

The error:

```
2019-07-26 13:35:47.517  INFO 89793 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [127.0.0.1:5672]
2019-07-26 13:35:52.533  WARN 89793 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Socket closed)
2019-07-26 13:35:52.538 ERROR 89793 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1810) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1784) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1765) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:306) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:957) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Also, I see in RabbitMQ's log that the Spring app drops connections:

```
2019-07-26 13:43:12.578 [warning] <0.4166.0> closing AMQP connection <0.4166.0> (127.0.0.1:50546 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not using Spring Boot, I ran into the same `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`, and it turned out to be an SSL issue. My RabbitMQ client was running with default settings (SSL turned off), while the server was configured with SSL on.

Once I changed the client code to call: [ConnectionFactory.useSslProtocol()](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/4.x.x/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html#useSslProtocol()) the issue was resolved.

With Spring Boot I believe this would mean setting:

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
```

(Note: you may also need to set the SSL algorithm: `spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm`)